# Parsing float in java with valid characters

Tags: java, performance, parsing

I try to make sure that a string is a valid float in java and don't want to use  Regex. The very first thing that comes to my mid is either use the `Float.valueOf(String)` with is equivalent to `Float.parseFloat(String)`.
These functions don't throw a `NumberFormatException`.

I understand these might be valid values in java. but when I want to communicate with other environments and languages, these are not valid there!!!

```
System.out.println(Float.parseFloat("4.f")); 
System.out.println(Float.parseFloat("2.d")); 
System.out.println(Float.parseFloat("0.45d")); 
System.out.println(Float.parseFloat("0.3f")); 
System.out.println(Float.parseFloat("0d")); 
System.out.println(Float.parseFloat("0d"));
```

result:

```
4.0
2.0
0.45
0.3
0.0
0.0
```

is there any elegant way to catch this upfront I know I can write my own parser but it is in loop that affects the performance. any thoughts?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you could convert to a string as youve done and then convert back to a float

Comment: What's your definition of "valid" then, if the "valid" java values are not valid for your application?

Comment: If the values are invalid in some other language then why Java throw error? Only way is to check the characters in the string before parsing.

Comment: @BheshGurung OP is complaining that Java *doesn't* throw an error for a value with `f` or `d` suffix, since "other environments and languages" will not accept that.

Comment: *"I don't want to use Regex"* Why?? It would be faster than parsing, and you can customize it to whatever subset of syntax you will allow.

Comment: 'These functions don't throw a `NumberFormatException`': they most certainly do. Unclear what your asking.

Comment: EJP, I meant the values I parse are not valid somewhere else but valid in java and I have to validate them before send it out in order to avoid an exception there.

Comment: Andreas, if regex is faster I would try but need to benchmark it. Thanks for the hint, I have never bench marked these two options.

Comment: holtc, I know what you mean but that causes a performance issue. I think i need to consider regex,  thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with @holtc solution and convert the original string to a float (then you know it's valid in Java) and then back to string to communicate to other systems:

```
String originalString = "4.f";
Float floatNum = Float.parseFloat(originalString);
String newString = floatNum.toString();
```

Actually you should pay attention to one more detail, locale, because other systems could be somewhere else and have a different separator for floats. In Brazil, for example, we use comma as decimal mark:

```
String originalString = "4.f";
Float floatNum = Float.parseFloat(originalString);
String newString = String.format(new Locale("pt", "BR"), "%.2f", floatNum);
```

Comment: Gustavo thanks for the solution but in my case I need to pass the float value as a string parameter to a batch processing and that throws an exception. locale is not my Problem.

Comment: Glad to help! If you are not worried about locale, any of the code snippets should work for you as you get a new string with a floating point number in a format that should be valid in any other system.